# Cannot remove a directory on NTFS file system even I used "rm -rf"

Tags: command-line, directory

I cannot remove a directory called “系统漏洞补丁”(please don't care the name of it) on Windows anyway, so I came to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and tried to remove it. But even I used `rm -rf 系统漏洞补丁` . It said: `rm: cannot remove '系统漏洞补丁': Directory not empty`
And here is the result of `ls -al 系统漏洞补丁`:

```
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user 0 Nov 5 17:51 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user 0 Nov 5 17:51 ..
```

and the `.` and `..` was colored with blue foreground and green background.
Are there any solutions?

Comment: Is it possible that directory is important to Windows?  Usually not a good idea to use Ubuntu/Linux to play in Windows stuff, things can happen like breaking Windows.  Is Windows in 'fast startup/shutdown' mode?

Comment: Have you searched for [similar questions](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=remove+directory+NTFS) on SO ?  I think you should just use `chkdisk \f` on Windows.